# Parse byte[] to JsonObject without converting to string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `byte[]` and I want to parse it as a `JsonObject` but I want to avoid converting the `byte[]` to a `string` for performance reasons.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var byteTest = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test".ToCharArray());

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JObject data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteTest))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ms))
{
   data = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(string));
}

return data;
```

But I'm getting this error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 1, position 1.` any ideas how I can do this correctly?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @SLaks. I'm trying to create json from the byte[]

Comment: At some point it's going to be converted to text as json is a text-based format. Would suggest avoiding this endeavor.

Comment: @batthing `test` is not valid JSON, whether it's represented as a byte array or not.

Comment: But the contents of your `byte[]` are invalid JSON, so you get an error.

Comment: I don't see you are serializing that byte[] anywhere? How you expect it to deserialize.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot: If the JSON parser is well-written, this can avoid allocating a very large string.

Comment: I see now @SLak, I'm going to work on this example and report back

Comment: Are you trying to convert a byte array to json (serializing it) or a byte array *containing* json back to something (deserializing it)? Please clarify what you mean by "parse" in this case. Also, it would be helpful if you could post what you actually hope to get as a final result.

Comment: Please note that if you intend to *deserialize* something by going from JSON back to an object or an object graph, that something you wish to deserialize **has to be json**. The text `test` is not json. If it supposed to be a json *string* it would have to be surrounded by quotes. Again, please clarify what your intentions are here and not just "I tried this and it didn't work". What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The c# literal `"test"` is not valid JSON because it evaluates to the JSON literal `test` -- without the quotes.  Since a JSON string literal must be quoted, you must do:

```
var byteTest = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\"test\"");
```

Next, `serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(string));` will return a **`string`**, which cannot be cast to a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  Thus the line

```
data = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(string));
```

will generate an `InvalidCastException`.

If for some reason you need to re-serialize that deserialized `string` (or any deserialized POCO) into a LINQ-to-JSON hierarchy, you can use [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject_1.htm):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteTest))
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        var value = serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(string));
        token = JToken.FromObject(value, serializer);
    }
```

Or if you really just needed to load a LINQ-to-JSON hierarchy directly from a stream, use [`JToken.ReadFrom`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ReadFrom.htm):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteTest))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(ms))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            token = JToken.ReadFrom(jsonReader);
        }
```

Here [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) is an abstract base class that can represent any of the data types (object, array, value, string, number) from the [JSON Standard](http://www.json.org/).   `JObject` cannot be used because a string value will actually get serialized to a [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) rather than a `JObject`.